# After setting record to dirty, store commits all fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm changing some values of the record and set it to dirty afterwards.
Although set writeAllFields to fields (which works fine if I edit my data via the edit form).

Controller method:

```
activateDeactivate: function(grid, selection, active) {
    for(var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        selection[i].data.status = (active) ? 1 : 0;
        selection[i].setDirty();
    }
    var store = this.getStore('Creatives');
    store.sync();
}
```

Store writer:

```
writer:{
        type:'json',
        writeAllFields:false,
        allowSingle: false //  always wrap data in an array
        //root: 'data'
    }
```

**Updated** Controller method:

```
activateDeactivate: function(grid, selection, active) {
    for(var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        selection[i].data.status = (active) ? 1 : 0;
        values = selection[i].data;
        selection[i].set(values);
    }
    var store = this.getStore('Creatives');
    store.sync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set the whole record dirty. You can just `set()` the new values. If they are dirty is internally determined by comparing `Record.modified` to `Record.data`.

Comment: Please see my update. It simply doesn't send anything to my backend.

Comment: So does it send *all* fields or *none at all*? You should ask one question at a time.

Comment: There's no ajax request send to my server if i don't set the records to dirty.

Comment: I'd guess, `set` doesn't work correctly because you are tampering with the private property `data`. See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-set, especially the part starting with `currentValue = me.get(fieldName);`.